# How to get sequence of array elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following array that is "separated" by "blocks". Each invisible block begins with a letter having number 5 next to it and finishes when another letter with 5 next to it appears.

```
a = [
     "F5","a4","g4","F5","a4","d4","F5","a4","g4","e3",
     "H5","a4",
     "Y5","a4","d4","Y5","g4","c3"
     ]
```

In this array there are 3 "blocks" like below.

- **Block1** --> *begins with first "F5" (index 0) and ends in "e3" (index
  9), just before the "H5".*
- **Block2** --> *begins with first "H5" (index 10) and ends in "a4" (index
  11), just before the "Y5".*
- **Block3** --> *begins with first "Y5" (index 12) and ends in "c3" (index
  17), when it reaches the end of array.*

What I'd like to get, is a sequence (from 1 to N) of each element within each block (Not within the array itself), where the output would be:

```
b = [
    ["F5",1],["a4",1],["g4",1],["F5",2],["a4",2],["d4",1],["F5",3],["a4",3],["g4",2],["e3",1],
    ["H5",1],["a4",1],
    ["Y5",1],["a4",1],["d4",1],["Y5",2],["g4",1],["c3",1]
    ]
```

With my current attempt I'm getting only the count of each element and not the sequence. How can this be done? Thanks

```
a = [
     "F5","a4","g4","F5","a4","d4","F5","a4","g4","e3",
     "H5","a4",
     "Y5","a4","d4","Y5","g4","c3"
     ]

b = []

a.each{|v| 
    b.push([v,a.count(v)])
}

=> [
    ["F5", 3], ["a4", 5], ["g4", 3], ["F5", 3], ["a4", 5], ["d4", 2], ["F5", 3], ["a4", 5], ["g4", 3], ["e3", 1], 
    ["H5", 1], ["a4", 5], 
    ["Y5", 2], ["a4", 5], ["d4", 2], ["Y5", 2], ["g4", 3], ["c3", 1]
    ]
```

Comment: Do the three "blocks" always have the same lengths?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem where the real question is "how do I better structure my data initially?"

Comment: @JaredBeck No, the "blocks" could have variable length

Comment: @anothermh but how could be structured the data initially? Since that is the original order

Comment: Are we actually given an array `a = [["F5","a4","g4","F5","a4","d4","F5", "a4","g4","e3"],  ["H5","a4"],  ["Y5","a4","d4","Y5","g4","c3"]]`? If so it would be more accurate to state the problem that way. If not, you need to give us the rule that tells us that the three blocks end with `"e3"`, `"a4"` and `"c3"`.

Comment: The input array is not array of arrays. The next block begins in position N, then the previous block ends in position N-1. I explained in original post saying "just before H5, just before Y5 and if there is no more blocks, then ends when the array ends.

Comment: @GerCas : You have 3 occurances of _F5_  in your example. So the first physical line would already be 3 blocks, making 5 blocks in total.

Comment: @user1934428 No, because there is a change of block when a different letter with number 5 appears. We could have N "F5" in a single.block but when H5 comes in that moment begins a new block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given the array

```
a = ["F5","a4","g4","F5","a4","d4","F5","a4","g4","e3",
     "H5","a4","Y5","a4","d4","Y5","g4","c3"]
```

The problem can be viewed as having two steps, the first being to convert `a` to

```
arr = [["F5","a4","g4","F5","a4","d4","F5","a4","g4","e3"],
       ["H5","a4"], ["Y5","a4","d4","Y5","g4","c3"]]
```

The second step is to construct the desired array from `arr`.

**Step 1**

I understand the rule for converting `a` to `arr` is as follows.

- the first element of each array of `arr` is a string of the form `YZ` that matches the regular expression `/[A-Z]\d/` (but the digit does not necessarily equal `5`).
- it is assumed that the first element of `a` always has the above property.
- the last element of each array `b` of `arr` is the last element of `a` or the element of `a` that precedes the first element of `a` following the element of `a` that corresponds to the first element of `b` that matches `/[A-Z]\d/`, but when compared with the first element of `b` the capital letters differ and the digits are equal.

We may write

```
frst = a.first
arr = a.slice_before do |s|
  (s[0].match?(/[A-Z]/) && s[0] != frst[0] && s[1] == frst[1]) ? 
    (frst = s) : false
end.to_a
  #=> [["F5", "a4", "g4", "F5", "a4", "d4", "F5", "a4", "g4", "e3"]],
  #    ["H5", "a4"], ["Y5", "a4", "d4", "Y5", "g4", "c3"]]
```

See [Enumerable#slice_before](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before).

**Step 2**

We may now convert `arr` to the desired array as follows.

```
arr.map do |e|
  h = Hash.new(0)
  e.map { |s| [s, h[s] += 1] }
end
  #=> [[["F5", 1], ["a4", 1], ["g4", 1], ["F5", 2], ["a4", 2], ["d4", 1],
  #     ["F5", 3], ["a4", 3], ["g4", 2], ["e3", 1]],
  #    [["H5", 1], ["a4", 1]],
  #    [["Y5", 1], ["a4", 1], ["d4", 1], ["Y5", 2], ["g4", 1], ["c3", 1]]]
```

Here [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) is used to create an empty hash `h` with a *default value* of zero. All that means is that if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns zero. As `h[k] += 1` can be seen as

```
h[k] = h[k] + 1
```

`h[k]` on the right returns `1` when `h` does not have a key `k`. Another way of writing that is

```
h[k] = h.fetch(k,0) + 1
```

See [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

Comment: Thanks Cary for your solution, the issue is the input arrays is not an array of arrays. The next block begins in position N, then the previous block ends in position N-1. I explained in original post saying "just before H5, just before Y5 and if there is no more blocks, then ends when the array ends.

Comment: OK, I had addressed that in an edit which I completed shortly after you posted your comment.

Comment: The blocks begins with elements containing letter and number 5. So, block begins in F5, H5 and Y5. The next block is determined when an element containing letter and number appears and the letter is different than the previous one. H5 is different than F5, then a new block begins. I hope make sense

Comment: This time it works pretty nice. Thanks so much for help amd explanation

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'd do:

Starting with:

```
a_ary = [
  'F5', 'a4', 'g4', 'F5', 'a4', 'd4', 'F5', 'a4', 'g4', 'e3', 
  'H5', 'a4', 
  'Y5', 'a4', 'd4', 'Y5', 'g4', 'c3'
]

BREAK_REGEX = /^.5/
```

I'd group the array by matching blocks, then grab the resulting chunks and flatten them back to the collected arrays.

```
grouped_ary = a_ary.slice_before(BREAK_REGEX)
                   .group_by { |a| a.first } # => {"F5"=>[["F5", "a4", "g4"], ["F5", "a4", "d4"], ["F5", "a4", "g4", "e3"]], "H5"=>[["H5", "a4"]], "Y5"=>[["Y5", "a4", "d4"], ["Y5", "g4", "c3"]]}
                   .values                   # => [[["F5", "a4", "g4"], ["F5", "a4", "d4"], ["F5", "a4", "g4", "e3"]], [["H5", "a4"]], [["Y5", "a4", "d4"], ["Y5", "g4", "c3"]]]
                   .map(&:flatten)           # => [["F5", "a4", "g4", "F5", "a4", "d4", "F5", "a4", "g4", "e3"], ["H5", "a4"], ["Y5", "a4", "d4", "Y5", "g4", "c3"]]
```

Then process those, counting the occurrences in each array, looping over them and output the element and the count, resetting the counter for each block:

```
b_ary = grouped_ary.flat_map{ |e|
  element_count = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }

  e.map { |i|
    element_count[i] += 1 
    [
      i, 
      element_count[i]
    ]
  }
}
```

Which results in:

```
b_ary
# => [["F5", 1],
#     ["a4", 1],
#     ["g4", 1],
#     ["F5", 2],
#     ["a4", 2],
#     ["d4", 1],
#     ["F5", 3],
#     ["a4", 3],
#     ["g4", 2],
#     ["e3", 1],
#     ["H5", 1],
#     ["a4", 1],
#     ["Y5", 1],
#     ["a4", 1],
#     ["d4", 1],
#     ["Y5", 2],
#     ["g4", 1],
#     ["c3", 1]]
#   ]
```

Here's what the very first step using `slice_before` creates:

```
a_ary.slice_before(BREAK_REGEX).to_a
# => [["F5", "a4", "g4"],
#     ["F5", "a4", "d4"],
#     ["F5", "a4", "g4", "e3"],
#     ["H5", "a4"],
#     ["Y5", "a4", "d4"],
#     ["Y5", "g4", "c3"]]
```

[Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html) is where the magic lies.

Comment: It's a powerful method; I've used it for lots of interesting things.

Answer (score 0):

I'd break this into a few functions.

```rb
require 'minitest/autorun'

# Split array where the given block returns true
def group_by_sequence(x)
  i = 0
  x.each_with_object([]) { |e, a|
    i += 1 if yield e
    a[i] = [] if a[i].nil?
    a[i] << e
  }
end

# Split array at each new "five", eg. going from "A5" to "B5"
def group_by_fives(x)
  li = nil
  group_by_sequence(x) { |e|
    l, n = e.chars
    li = l if li.nil?
    if n == '5' && li != l
      li = l
      true
    else
      false
    end
  }
end

# Given [A,B,C,B], returns [[A,1], [B,1], [C,1], [B,2]]
def add_counts_by_group(x)
  group_by_fives(x).flat_map { |group|
    count = {}
    group.map { |e|
      count[e] = count[e].to_i + 1
      [e, count[e]]
    }
  }
end

class Test < Minitest::Test
  def test_add_counts_by_group
    assert_equal(
      [
        ["F5",1],["a4",1],["g4",1],["F5",2],["a4",2],["d4",1],["F5",3],["a4",3],["g4",2],["e3",1],
        ["H5",1],["a4",1],
        ["Y5",1],["a4",1],["d4",1],["Y5",2],["g4",1],["c3",1]
      ],
      add_counts_by_group([
        "F5","a4","g4","F5","a4","d4","F5","a4","g4","e3",
        "H5","a4",
        "Y5","a4","d4","Y5","g4","c3"
      ])
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry for my poor knowledge, but I don't now how to test it. Where it goes input and which is the output?

Comment: @ger-cas save to a file `x.rb`. Run the file with `ruby x.rb`. You may need to `gem install minitest`

Comment: I've installed minitest and paste all your code and I didn´t get any error, only get this `=> :test_add_counts_by_group` But I don´t know where to insert the input array and where is the output array.